# Java gRPC server bounds to IPv6 port

Tags: java, grpc

Is there a way to configure gRPC server to bind to IPv4 0.0.0.0 and port instead of IPv6 ::: and port?

Comment: Is there an issue with the grpc-java behavior you are trying to avoid? The default binding behavior generally works for both IPv4 and IPv6. If it doesn't for you, describe what produces failures and what OS you are using.

Comment: My mistake, it is working for both

Answer (score 0):

Start your program with Java option `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html